# working session variable inside jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I am having trouble recording the following _session variable inside my jquery function. I essentially want to grab the value of the coupon code and store it there.

```
<input type="text" oninput="calculate()" name="couponCode"  id="couponCode"  value="" placeholder="Please Enter Coupon Code" required>
<script>
$(function() {
 $("#signInButton2").click(function(){
<?php $_SESSION['userCoupon'] = echo "<script> $('#couponCode').val(); </script>"; ?> 

});

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to post to a controller to set the session variable I believe. What you are currently doing doesn't make sense. I don't think echo returns anything, it may return void though, but this will parse, not run, echoing out a script tag inside of your other script tag.

Comment: PHP is server side, once the page has loaded, you can't use it again without another page load or using something like ajax.

Comment: you can use sesion variables to store variables that can be reused in other php page, my concern is calling it within a jquery function, where it need to be equal to the value of the input upon button click

Comment: To do that, you have to make a post to the server. You cannot do this with solely client-side Javascript.

Comment: im not sure how to do that

Comment: this is where i would need help thank

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and easy using jSON. I will get a lot of flak for using jSON in this manner, but too bad everyone.

This should work just fine...

```
    $(function()
    {
        $("#signInButton2").click(function()
        {
            var temp = $('#couponCode').val();
            example(temp)
        });
    });


    function example(number)
    {
        $.get("example_set_session.php",
        {
            number: number
        });
    }
```

in example_set_session.php...

```
    <?php 

        $example_number = $_GET['number'];

        $_SESSION['userCoupon'] = $example;

    ?>
```